# Informix initialisation fails because the master daemon dies

Tags: database, informix

I'm trying to install a Informix Developer instance on a debian 7 server, to get to test a couple of programs with Informix as Database engine. I tried all solutions I could find googling the error messages, but it kept me going back and forth. Can any body see what my problem is?

The log:

```
14:46:46  Parameter's user-configured value was adjusted. 

(DS_MAX_SCANS)
14:46:46  Parameter's user-configured value was adjusted. (ONLIDX_MAXMEM)
14:46:46  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Started.
14:46:46  Warning: The IBM IDS Developer Edition license restriction limits
14:46:46  the total shared memory size for this server to 1048576 KB.
14:46:46  The maximum allowable shared memory was reset to this size to start the database server. 
14:46:46  Requested shared memory segment size rounded from 8308KB to 8840KB

Sat Dec 19 14:46:48 2015

14:46:48  Successfully added a bufferpool of page size 2K.

14:46:48  Event alarms enabled.  ALARMPROG = '/etc/Informix/etc/alarmprogram.sh'
14:46:48  Booting Language <c> from module <>
14:46:48  Loading Module <CNULL>
14:46:48  Booting Language <builtin> from module <>
14:46:48  Loading Module <BUILTINNULL>
14:46:53  DR: DRAUTO is 0 (Off)
14:46:53  DR: ENCRYPT_HDR is 0 (HDR encryption Disabled)
14:46:53  Event notification facility epoll enabled.
14:46:53  CCFLAGS2 value set to 0x200
14:46:53  SQL_FEAT_CTRL value set to 0x8008
14:46:53  SQL_DEF_CTRL value set to 0x4b0
14:46:53  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC5DE Software Serial Number AAA#B000000
14:46:53  requested number of KAIO events (32768) exceeds limit (31437). using 31437.
14:46:54  Value of FULL_DISK_INIT has been changed to 0.

14:46:54  Performance Advisory: The physical log size is smaller than the recommended size for a
server configured with RTO_SERVER_RESTART.
14:46:54   Results: Fast recovery performance might not be optimal.
14:46:54   Action: For best fast recovery performance when RTO_SERVER_RESTART is enabled,
increase the physical log size to at least 66602 KB. For servers
configured with a large buffer pool, this might not be necessary. 
14:46:54  IBM Informix Dynamic Server Initialized -- Complete Disk Initialized.
14:46:54  Started 1 B-tree scanners.
14:46:54  B-tree scanner threshold set at 5000.
14:46:54  B-tree scanner range scan size set to -1.
14:46:54  B-tree scanner ALICE mode set to 6.
14:46:54  B-tree scanner index compression level set to med.
14:46:54  Warning: Invalid (non-existent/blobspace/disabled) dbspace listed
           in DBSPACETEMP: 'tempdbs'
14:46:55  The Master Daemon Died
14:46:55  invoke_alarm(): /bin/sh -c '/etc/Informix/etc/alarmprogram.sh 5 6 "Internal Subsystem failure: 'MT'" "The Master Daemon Died" "" 6069'
14:46:55  invoke_alarm(): mt_exec failed, status 32512, errno 0
14:46:55  PANIC: Attempting to bring system down
```

And if it helps the onconfig file the database

```
    ROOTNAME rootdbs
ROOTPATH /home/informix_storage/rootdbs
ROOTOFFSET 0
ROOTSIZE 2000000
MIRROR 0
MIRRORPATH $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/demo_on.root_mirror

MIRROROFFSET 0

PHYSFILE 29792
PLOG_OVERFLOW_PATH $INFORMIXDIR/tmp

PHYSBUFF 512

LOGFILES 4
LOGSIZE 7168
DYNAMIC_LOGS 2

LOGBUFF 256

LTXHWM 70

LTXEHWM 80

MSGPATH /etc/Informix/informix_inst_01.log

CONSOLE $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/online.con

TBLTBLFIRST 0
TBLTBLNEXT 0

TBLSPACE_STATS 1

DBSPACETEMP tempdbs

SBSPACETEMP 

SBSPACENAME sbspace
SYSSBSPACENAME 

ONDBSPACEDOWN 2


SERVERNUM 0
DBSERVERNAME informix_inst_01
DBSERVERALIASES dr_informix_inst_01, lo_informix_inst_01

FULL_DISK_INIT  0               

NETTYPE ipcshm,1,50,CPU
LISTEN_TIMEOUT 60
MAX_INCOMPLETE_CONNECTIONS 1024
FASTPOLL 1
NUMFDSERVERS 4

NS_CACHE host=900,service=900,user=900,group=900

MULTIPROCESSOR 1
VPCLASS cpu,num=1,noage
VP_MEMORY_CACHE_KB 0

SINGLE_CPU_VP 1


AUTO_TUNE 1

CLEANERS 2

DIRECT_IO 1

LOCKS 40000

DEF_TABLE_LOCKMODE page

RESIDENT 0
SHMBASE 0x44000000L
SHMVIRTSIZE 101376
SHMADD 3165
EXTSHMADD 8192
SHMTOTAL 0
SHMVIRT_ALLOCSEG 0,3

SHMNOACCESS 

CKPTINTVL 300
RTO_SERVER_RESTART 60

BLOCKTIMEOUT 3600

CONVERSION_GUARD 2

RESTORE_POINT_DIR $INFORMIXDIR/tmp


TXTIMEOUT 300
DEADLOCK_TIMEOUT 60

HETERO_COMMIT 0

TAPEDEV /dev/null
TAPEBLK 32

TAPESIZE 0

LTAPEDEV /dev/null
LTAPEBLK 32

LTAPESIZE 0

BAR_ACT_LOG $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/bar_act.log
BAR_DEBUG_LOG $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/bar_dbug.log
BAR_DEBUG 0
BAR_MAX_BACKUP 0
BAR_RETRY 1
BAR_NB_XPORT_COUNT 20
BAR_XFER_BUF_SIZE 31
RESTARTABLE_RESTORE ON
BAR_PROGRESS_FREQ 0
BAR_BSALIB_PATH $INFORMIXDIR/lib/libbsapsm.so
BACKUP_FILTER 
RESTORE_FILTER 
BAR_PERFORMANCE 0

BAR_CKPTSEC_TIMEOUT 15
PSM_DBS_POOL DBSPOOL

PSM_LOG_POOL LOGPOOL


DD_HASHSIZE 31

DD_HASHMAX 10

DS_HASHSIZE 31

DS_POOLSIZE 127

PC_HASHSIZE 31
PC_POOLSIZE 127

PRELOAD_DLL_FILE 

STMT_CACHE 0
STMT_CACHE_HITS 0
STMT_CACHE_SIZE 512
STMT_CACHE_NOLIMIT 0

STMT_CACHE_NUMPOOL 1

USEOSTIME 0
STACKSIZE 64
ALLOW_NEWLINE 0

USELASTCOMMITTED "NONE"

FILLFACTOR 90
MAX_FILL_DATA_PAGES 0
BTSCANNER num=1,threshold=5000,rangesize=-1,alice=6,compression=default

ONLIDX_MAXMEM 5242880

MAX_PDQPRIORITY 100
DS_MAX_QUERIES 5
DS_TOTAL_MEMORY 26214400
DS_MAX_SCANS 5
DS_NONPDQ_QUERY_MEM 1310720

DATASKIP 

OPTCOMPIND 2
DIRECTIVES 1
EXT_DIRECTIVES 0
OPT_GOAL -1
IFX_FOLDVIEW 1
STATCHANGE 10

USTLOW_SAMPLE 1

BATCHEDREAD_TABLE 1

BATCHEDREAD_INDEX 1


EXPLAIN_STAT 1
IFX_EXTEND_ROLE 1
SECURITY_LOCALCONNECTION 
UNSECURE_ONSTAT 
ADMIN_USER_MODE_WITH_DBSA 
ADMIN_MODE_USERS 
SSL_KEYSTORE_LABEL 

TLS_VERSION 

PLCY_POOLSIZE 127
PLCY_HASHSIZE 31
USRC_POOLSIZE 127

USRC_HASHSIZE 31


SQL_LOGICAL_CHAR OFF


SEQ_CACHE_SIZE 10

ENCRYPT_HDR 
ENCRYPT_SMX 
ENCRYPT_CDR 0
ENCRYPT_CIPHERS 
ENCRYPT_MAC 
ENCRYPT_MACFILE 

ENCRYPT_SWITCH 


CDR_EVALTHREADS 1,2
CDR_DSLOCKWAIT 5
CDR_QUEUEMEM 4096
CDR_NIFCOMPRESS 0
CDR_SERIAL 0
CDR_DBSPACE 
CDR_QHDR_DBSPACE 
CDR_QDATA_SBSPACE 
CDR_SUPPRESS_ATSRISWARN 
CDR_DELAY_PURGE_DTC 0
CDR_LOG_LAG_ACTION ddrblock
CDR_LOG_STAGING_MAXSIZE 0
CDR_MAX_DYNAMIC_LOGS 0
GRIDCOPY_DIR $INFORMIXDIR
CDR_TSINSTANCEID 0
CDR_MAX_FLUSH_SIZE 50
CDR_AUTO_DISCOVER 0

CDR_MEM 0


DRAUTO 0
DRINTERVAL 0
HDR_TXN_SCOPE NEAR_SYNC
DRTIMEOUT 30
HA_ALIAS 
HA_FOC_ORDER SDS,HDR,RSS
DRLOSTFOUND $INFORMIXDIR/etc/dr.lostfound
DRIDXAUTO 0
LOG_INDEX_BUILDS 
SDS_ENABLE 
SDS_TIMEOUT 20
SDS_TEMPDBS 
SDS_PAGING 
SDS_LOGCHECK 10
SDS_ALTERNATE NONE
SDS_FLOW_CONTROL 0
UPDATABLE_SECONDARY 0
FAILOVER_CALLBACK 
FAILOVER_TX_TIMEOUT 0
TEMPTAB_NOLOG 0
DELAY_APPLY 0
STOP_APPLY 0
LOG_STAGING_DIR 
RSS_FLOW_CONTROL 0
SMX_NUMPIPES 1
ENABLE_SNAPSHOT_COPY 0
SMX_COMPRESS 0
SMX_PING_INTERVAL 10
SMX_PING_RETRY 6

CLUSTER_TXN_SCOPE SERVER

ON_RECVRY_THREADS 2

OFF_RECVRY_THREADS 5

DUMPDIR $INFORMIXDIR/tmp
DUMPSHMEM 1
DUMPGCORE 0
DUMPCORE 0

DUMPCNT 1

ALARMPROGRAM $INFORMIXDIR/etc/alarmprogram.sh
ALRM_ALL_EVENTS 0
STORAGE_FULL_ALARM 600,3

SYSALARMPROGRAM $INFORMIXDIR/etc/evidence.sh

RAS_PLOG_SPEED  14896           

RAS_LLOG_SPEED 0


EILSEQ_COMPAT_MODE 0

QSTATS 0

WSTATS 0


USERMAPPING OFF

SP_AUTOEXPAND 1
SP_THRESHOLD 0

SP_WAITTIME 30


AUTOLOCATE 0


DEFAULTESCCHAR \

MQSERVER 
MQCHLLIB 

MQCHLTAB 

REMOTE_SERVER_CFG 
REMOTE_USERS_CFG 

S6_USE_REMOTE_SERVER_CFG 0
LOW_MEMORY_RESERVE 0

LOW_MEMORY_MGR 0

GSKIT_VERSION 
INFORMIXCONTIME 60

INFORMIXCONRETRY 1

JVPPROPFILE $INFORMIXDIR/extend/krakatoa/.jvpprops
JVPLOGFILE $INFORMIXDIR/tmp/jvp.log
JVPARGS -Dcom.ibm.tools.attach.enable=no

JVPCLASSPATH INFORMIXDIR/extend/krakatoa/jdbc.jar


BUFFERPOOL default,memory='auto'
BUFFERPOOL size=2k,memory=500MB
NETTYPE onsoctcp,1,150,NET
NETTYPE drsoctcp,1,150,NET
AUTO_TUNE_SERVER_SIZE SMALL
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Which version of Informix are you attempting to bring up?  …The information is there…12.10.FC5DE.  That's almost the most recent version; 12.10.FC6DE was released a month or so ago.  The CCFLAGS2, SQL_FEAT_CTRL and SQL_DEF_CTRL values worried me at first, but I found the same values in my own server initialization log file — so that shouldn't be the issue.  The DBSPACETEMP warning should be just that — a warning, not an error or a cause of trouble.

Comment: It's curious that the server has gotten through as much work as it has before failing.  Have you tried `oninit -ivwy` (where the `-i` is 'initialize'; `-v` is 'verbose'; `-w` is 'wait until ready`, and `-y` is 'assume yes; don't ask me questions').  It might tell you which step it is at differently from the online log you show.  I forget, can you get installation support for Developer Edition (that's the DE in the version number)?  If so, speak to IBM/Informix Tech Support.  Do you have enough resources configured?  Check the release notes (machine notes) for what you need.

Comment: Are the ports you need accessible and available?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: No, Unfortunately I couldn't.

Thank you for the ideas, Jonathan!